# Add Water mark to custom video recorder

Tags: java, android

I am using custom video recorder app I want to add two watermarks in my video one is a square which should be on top left corner and a triangle which is on bottom right corner

I want it on the video which is recorded.

This is what I want to achieve:

[image]

I cannot find anything on the internet regarding this. I do have researched it extensively

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Create an `ImageButton` with these attributes...
`android:src="@drawable/TheWaterMark android:layout_alignParentTop="True" android:layout_alignParentLeft="True"`
do the opposite to the bottom one...

Edit: I realized something, are you using xml-shapes or drawable-images here?

Comment: Yes i am using xml shapes

Comment: Alright then, this will work with this: android:src="@drawable/filename"

Comment: No need to add ".xml" to the filename.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to create custom video recording and add water marker in the video then try this dependency in the github:
https://github.com/maheshpaliwal/vsrwm